# Count records that start with specific letters

Tags: mysql, sql

I have names which looks like this:

- Andrew
- Arthur
- Barry

I would like to do a query which finds out how many records start with An, Ar, Ba. e.g.

- An, 1
- Ar, 1
- Ba, 1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Select COUNT(*),SUBSTRING(column_name,1,2) FROM table_name GROUP BY SUBSTRING(column_name,1,2)
```

Comment: Cool, what I had a name like P eter and Peter, any way to trim the spaces out?

Comment: ofcource first trim out the values TRIM(column_name)

Comment: @jimy - I believe that `TRIM` will remove only the leading or trailing spaces (or both), not the ones that are in the middle. @Tom could use `REPLACE(column_name,' ','')`

Comment: @Lamak `REPLACE` will do that `SELECT REPLACE( '     h m',' ', '')`

Comment: @jimy - yeap, that's what I put on my comment ;-)

Comment: @Tom: That would make an interesting *new* question. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(name, 1, 2), COUNT(*) AS "Count"
FROM mytable
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(name, 1, 2)
```

Comment: Why are you aliasing `COUNT(*)`? :)

Comment: I come from the SQL Server world, if you don't alias a function then the column header will be blank.  Is it not like that in MySQL?

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a peculiar joke of mine. Actually I meant to ask why you aliased COUNT but didn't do that to SUBSTRING. :) Sorry again, should have been more serious there.

Comment: ah. that's an excellent question. i probably should have aliased it. i do this kind of thing often, and i usually don't alias my category name, just the counts. i will often have multiple calculations columns, MAX, COUNT, MIN, AVERAGE, etc. you gotta label these or you get really confused.

Comment: Being a SQL Server man myself, I, too, can't boast of being capable to go a long way without aliasing columns. And what you have described is quite a familiar situation with me. Often I would play with aggregates in SSMS to get some proper grouping, and after some time I would decide to use the result set as a subquery, and then - oops! "What is that COUNT(*) thingy is supposed to be called like, sir?" – "Hey, come on, I don't even use it in my query!" – "I don't care. You should alias it, or I'll never ever in my life run a query of yours. Sir." Not that I had plenty of choice there, you see.